# Why does a linux thread function work in windows?

Tags: c, windows, linux, pthreads, cygwin

I am compiling this program with gcc from cygwin package on my windows machine

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void* thread_function(void)
{
    printf("hello");
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread_id[argc-1];
    int i;
    int status;
    printf("argc is %d ",argc-1);
    for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++)
    {
        pthread_create (&thread_id[i], NULL , &thread_function, NULL);
    }  

    for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++)
        pthread_join(thread_id[i],NULL);   
}
```

It compiles and creates a.exe

When I run it in cmd

```
./a.exe 2 3
```

The output is

```
argc is 2 hellohello

Question :
```

**pthread.h and this thread function are related to linux os then why does it work with windows?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beyond the pthread.h, cygwin is an entire  unix-like enviroment, mainly based on gnu utilities, with some solaris stuff too.

You can compile and use unix software inside the cygwin environment, but you can not distribute your exe file just like that. Every single windows machine would need to have installed and configure a cigwin environment.

Cygwin apps are not 100% efficient or reliable on windows environment due to OS design differences. Just as windows apps are not 100% reliable or efficient when using wine, although Cygwin apps are compiled natively in windows.

Other environment/libraries/compilers also provide ways for using posix functions. One of the most successful being Mingw, which provides libraries implemented on top of win32 calls and does not need an extra environment.

On top of that Cygwin apps must comply with the GPL2 terms, so you must give your source code away with the app when using cygwin compiled binaries, Mingw runtime libraries are officially in the public domain, so you can keep your source code to yourself if you desire.

http://www.mingw.org/ 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin

Comment: MinGW does not provide a POSIX layer for Windows. That's exactly what the Cygwin DLL is for. MinGW stands for "Minimalist GNU for Windows" which means gcc and the rest of the GNU toolchain plus headers for accessing the Windows system libraries.

Comment: @ak2 Call it minimalistic posix then . GNU is Not Unix but is very well based on it. Although mingw is minimalistic, a lot of stuff is added on Codelite and Code::Blocks all in one downloads. Building from from source and you add a lot more anyway to acquire more functionality. Cigwin is a complete environment with sys V init, packaging/libc/shells/etc , Mingw is a compiler + libraries + utilities.

Answer (score 12):

They are not "Linux threads", they are **P**​OSIX **thread**​s. Cygwin provides a POSIX compatibility layer, including `pthread.h`.

Comment: They can be. But a compatibility layer is welcome to present any interface it likes.

Comment: So you mean when ever i want to make the windows version of my linux application, i should compile my linux apps source code this way (with help of such compatibility layer program such cygwin) and its .exe will be ready ?

Comment: Depends. Cygwin doesn't provide *everything*, or your app may not need what Cygwin provides.

Comment: Is there any other such program/package which provide such all things?

Comment: Mr.32: There's MinGW, which provides a very small part of POSIX, along with most of the Win32 API. It also has a version of pthreads, and is much more C99 compliant (if not completely) than Visual Studio.

Comment: Well technically MinGW does not offer the huge POSIX libraries and utilities, because is impractical because of OS design and users platform focus. POSIX is way too big to be implemented without some very good reasons. Also technically Visual Studio does NOT support C.It supports C++, which includes a subset of C. C does have some differences and incompatibilities with C++, minor but they do exist.Also until Windows XP (don't know about 7)the NT kernel did support POSIX1 due to a 90's FIPS US federal regulation, existing side by side with win32, accessible with the _ prefix: _open _fork _execl